# Why can't I add a new migration?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, migration, entity-framework-migrations

adding - removing - getting migration , all migration commands are not functioning and give the same result... "Build Failed"

I was trying to remove migration and so I did... but after removing the migration I forgot to update database, and tried adding the new migration. and since then all commands are giving me the same result "Build Failed".

Comment: try adding "-v" to get a more detailed exception and include that in your question. I'm guessing that ef thinks there are fields/tables there that don't exist.   OR, close VS, re-open and try to rebuild.  Check the exceptions thrown.

Comment: Pls check the `Output` or `Error List` panel in visual studio to check what is the detailed message for building failure and share the details with us.